# Is there a way to edit a Buttons properties? Discord.py, discord-components

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering a way to edit a discordcomponent button property. The one I am having most trouble to understand is `component.Button.set_disabled()`. I didn't find any answers. Please can someone help? By the way this is from the `discord-components` library. I want to make a tictactoe game in Discord with buttons and other components.

Answer (score 0):

so i just checked the source code for `discord-components` and if im correct(probably wrong) you can just get your button class and set it like this

```py
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    button1 = Button(label = "button1", custom_id = "button1")
    button2 = Button(label = "button2", custom_id = "button2")
    button3 = Button(label = "button3", custom_id = "button3")
    msg = await ctx.send("button", components = [button1, button2, button3])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "button1")
    await interaction.set_disabled(True)
    await interaction.send(f"Disabled")
```

or this

```py
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    button1 = Button(label = "button1", custom_id = "button1")
    button2 = Button(label = "button2", custom_id = "button2")
    button3 = Button(label = "button3", custom_id = "button3")
    msg = await ctx.send("button", components = [button1, button2, button3])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "button1")
    await button1.set_disabled(True)
    await interaction.send(f"Disabled")
```

Comment: This did not work for me at all. Please can u come up with another solution?

Comment: did you get any errors? also i was way late to this

Comment: no i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py actually stopped getting updates, you need discord.py 2.0 but discord.py is stuck at 1.7.3
You need to install nextcord.py here is more info [here](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1)

Comment: I did but idk how to get the buttons property and change it if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    button1 = Button(label = "button1", custom_id = "button1")
    button2 = Button(label = "button2", custom_id = "button2")
    button3 = Button(label = "button3", custom_id = "button3")
    button1disabled = Button(label = "button1", custom_id = "button1", disabled = True)
    button2disabled = Button(label = "button2", custom_id = "button2", disabled = True)
    button3disabled = Button(label = "button3", custom_id = "button3", disabled = True)
    msg = await ctx.send("button", components = [button1, button2, button3])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "button1")
    await interaction.respond(type = 7, content = msg, components = [button1disabled, button2disabled, button3disabled])
    await interaction.send(f"Disabled")
```